# Alter bash tab completion to make it more like zsh

Tags: macos, bash, unix, zsh

I'm on a Mac and the cp and mv commands are killing me due to them copying the contents of a directory if a trailing slash is present.  It has bitten me more than once when I use tab completion to specify the directory I want to copy.

I have noticed zsh has a neat feature that removes the trailing slash if it's not needed after a space or enter key is pressed.  Is there any way to have bash mimic this behavior?

Comment: Why not just run zsh? It's built into Mac OS X.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to bash after 12 years of using it...  zsh seems like it requires a lot of setup to get it working similar to bash?

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25734/how-to-make-bash-tab-completion-act-more-like-zsh) on [unix.se]. [Please don't do that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073)

Answer (score 0):

Bash completion can't capture space or enter key. It's for tab-key only.

To your question, I think you can write a little wrapper script to remove the trailing slash before pass the command line to the actual cp/mv programs.

For example, ~/bin/my_mv:

```
#!/bin/bash

argv=("$@")
last="${argv[$# - 1]}"
last="${last%/}"
argv[$# - 1]="$last"

mv "${argv[@]}"
```